# How to sort recyclerView, Bold item if unread and unbold if item opened?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have 2 Activities in my application.

- activityMain contain 3 Fragments
  The third fragment is a conversations list. This is a recylerView where each Item leads to a specific chat.
- activityConversation contains a Chat.

First, i would like to sort the conversations in the the recyclerView in order of "Last actives". The most recent active should be displayed on top of the list, the second last active on second postition etc...

Secondly, each Item of the recyclerView contains a Textview. For each item,  I would like to display the last message posted in the related chat in this Texview.

Finally, i would like to display these Item textViews  in Bold since the conversation has not been opened until the last chat update.

Has anyone an Idea to help me achieve that?

Here my Chat Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable._background_black_lchatxxxhdpi) ;

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    LinearLayout leftNav = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.conv_left_nav);
    LinearLayout helperAdmin = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_participant_admin, leftNav, false);
    leftNav.addView(helperAdmin);


    final EditText input_post = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_post);


    context = this;
    input_post.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ImageButton btn_submit = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
            btn_submit.setEnabled(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString().trim()));



        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("conversationId"))
        conversationId = intent.getStringExtra("conversationId");

    rpcHelper = new RPCHelper(context, this);
    String unique_device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.i("US", unique_device_id);
    rpcHelper.loginOrRegister(unique_device_id, new AsyncResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
            refreshConversation();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
        }
    });

    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, "us", null, Statics.DB_VERSION);

    userInConv = dbHelper.dbReader.getUserInConversation(Integer.parseInt(conversationId));
    storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    leftRecycler = (RecyclerView) helperAdmin.findViewById(R.id.conv_left_recycler);

    //mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    leftLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    leftRecycler.setLayoutManager(leftLayoutManager);


    leftAdapter = new ConvLeftAdapter(userInConv, storageDir, Integer.parseInt(conversationId));
    leftRecycler.setAdapter(leftAdapter);

    helpersImg = new View[3];
    helpers = new DataBaseReader.User[3];

    photos = dbHelper.dbReader.getPhotosInConversation(Integer.parseInt(conversationId));

    photoRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.photo_recycler);
    photoLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, Math.max(photos.length, 1));
    photoRecycler.setLayoutManager(photoLayoutManager);

    rightAdapter = new ConvRightAdapter(photos, storageDir, context);
    photoRecycler.setAdapter(rightAdapter);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Statics.ACTION_NEW_POST);
    this.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("new", " message");
            refreshConversation();
        }
    }, filter);


}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if (intent.hasExtra("conversationId"))
        conversationId = intent.getStringExtra("conversationId");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_conversation, menu);


    DataBaseReader.Conversation conversation = dbHelper.dbReader.getConversation(conversationId);
    DataBaseReader.User owner = dbHelper.dbReader.getConversationOwner(conversationId);

    final ImageView owner_img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_userprofilpic);
    TextView owner_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_username_owner);
    TextView owner_city = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_usercity_owner);
    TextView conversation_question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text);

    owner_name.setText(owner.name);
    owner_city.setText(owner.city);
    conversation_question.setText(conversation.question.text);

    conversation_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text);
            int maxLines = TextViewCompat.getMaxLines(text);

            if (maxLines==2){
                text.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            }
            else{
                text.setMaxLines(2);
            }
                                }


        });


    rpcHelper.getPhoto(storageDir + "/", owner.photo, new AsyncResponseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {
            owner_img.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
        }

    });

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void refreshConversation(){

    dbHelper.dbSyncer.syncPosts(rpcHelper.user_id, new AsyncResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {

            DataBaseReader.Post[] posts = dbHelper.dbReader.getPosts(conversationId);

            postsRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.posts_recycler);
            postsLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
            postsRecycler.setLayoutManager(postsLayoutManager);

            postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(posts, storageDir, rpcHelper);
            postsRecycler.setAdapter(postsAdapter);

            postsRecycler.scrollToPosition(postsAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);


        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {

        }
    });
```

/*
        rpcHelper.getPosts(conversationId, new AsyncResponseListener(){

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
            LinearLayout posts_root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.posts_root);
            posts_root.removeAllViews();

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                Log.d("Conv refresh", response.get(i) + "");
                final JSONObject jConversation = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                LinearLayout post;
                if (jConversation.getString("userId") == rpcHelper.user_id) {
                    post = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_chatpost_sent, posts_root, false);
                }
                else{
                    post = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_chatpost_received, posts_root, false);
                    ((TextView)post.findViewById(R.id.post_name_)).setText(jConversation.getString("name"));
                }
                ((TextView)post.findViewById(R.id.lbl_message_chat)).setText(jConversation.getString("text"));

                posts_root.addView(post);

            }

            hideProcessDialog();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {

        }
    });*/
}

public void onSubmit(View v){

    final EditText input_post = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_post);
    String post_text = input_post.getText().toString();

    rpcHelper.post(conversationId, post_text, new AsyncResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
            refreshConversation();
            input_post.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {

        }
    });


}


    Button no = (Button)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            helpersImg[0] = null;
            helpersImg[1] = null;
            helpersImg[2] = null;
            helpers[0] = null;
            helpers[1] = null;
            helpers[2] = null;
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}

public void onSelectUser(View v){
    View vi = snapHelper.findSnapView(participantsLayoutManager);

    if (helpersImg[0] == vi || helpersImg[1] == vi || helpersImg[2] == vi)
        return;


    Log.i("get helper Id", ""+ participantsAdapter.selectedUserId);

    ImageView photo = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.img_userprofilpic);
    photo.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmap = photo.getDrawingCache();

    ImageView helperImage = null;
    if (helpersImg[0] == null) {
        helperImage = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reward_dialog_helper0);
        helpersImg[0] = vi;
        helperImage.setImageBitmap(bmap);
        photo.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        helpers[0] = userInConv[participantsAdapter.selectedUserId];
    }
    else if (helpersImg[1] == null){
        helperImage = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reward_dialog_helper1);
        helpersImg[1] = vi;
        helperImage.setImageBitmap(bmap);
        photo.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);


        helpers[1] = userInConv[participantsAdapter.selectedUserId];
    }
    else if (helpersImg[2] == null){
        helperImage = (ImageView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reward_dialog_helper2);
        helpersImg[2] = vi;
        helperImage.setImageBitmap(bmap);
        photo.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(123, 123, 123), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        helpers[1] = userInConv[participantsAdapter.selectedUserId];
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}

/**private void showTipDialog(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_tip, null);

    final EditText value = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tip_value);
    final SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    sb.setMax(50);
    sb.setProgress(5);

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {

            progress = (Math.round(progress/5 ))*5;
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);

            value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Convert text to integer. Do you already use editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER), don't you?
            Integer enteredProgress = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());
            sb.setProgress(enteredProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}});

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    Button ok = (Button)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Button no = (Button)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}*/

public void removeHelper(View v){
    int index = 0;
    if (v == alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reward_dialog_helper0)){
        index = 0;
    }
    else if (v == alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reward_dialog_helper1)){
        index = 1;
    }
    else if (v == alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reward_dialog_helper2)){
        index = 2;
    }
    if (helpersImg[index] == null){
        return;
    }

    ImageView photo = (ImageView) helpersImg[index].findViewById(R.id.img_userprofilpic);
    photo.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    photo.clearColorFilter();
    helpersImg[index] = null;
    helpers[index] = null;

    ImageView imv = (ImageView)v;
    imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.stroke_rounded_corners_white);
}

private void showProcessDialog(){
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setTitle("Processing");
    pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.show();
}

private void hideProcessDialog(){
    pd.hide();
}

@Override
public void onInternetConnectionLost() {

}

@Override
public void onInternetConnectionFound() {

}

public void onTakePicture(View v){
   Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Statics.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   }
}

public void onTakePictureFromGallery(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Select Picture"), Statics.REQUEST_PROFILE_IMAGE_GALLERY);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    if ((requestCode == Statics.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE || requestCode == Statics.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_0
            || requestCode == Statics.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_1 || requestCode == Statics.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_2) && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras == null){
            return;
        }
        imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        addPhoto(imageBitmap);

    }
    else if (requestCode == Statics.REQUEST_PROFILE_IMAGE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        try {
            imageBitmap = getBitmapFromUri(data.getData());
            addPhoto(imageBitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void addPhoto(Bitmap image) {
    DataBaseReader.Conversation c = dbHelper.dbReader.getConversation(conversationId);

    String encodedImage = encodeBitmap(image);
    rpcHelper.addPhotosToQuestion("" + c.question.id, encodedImage, null, null, new AsyncResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {

            dbHelper.dbSyncer.sync(rpcHelper.user_id, new AsyncResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
                    photos = dbHelper.dbReader.getPhotosInConversation(Integer.parseInt(conversationId));
                    photoRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.photo_recycler);
                    photoLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, Math.max(photos.length, 1));
                    photoRecycler.setLayoutManager(photoLayoutManager);

                    rightAdapter = new ConvRightAdapter(photos, storageDir, context);
                    photoRecycler.setAdapter(rightAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse() {
                    photos = dbHelper.dbReader.getPhotosInConversation(Integer.parseInt(conversationId));
                    photoRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.photo_recycler);
                    photoLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, Math.max(photos.length, 1));
                    photoRecycler.setLayoutManager(photoLayoutManager);

                    rightAdapter = new ConvRightAdapter(photos, storageDir, context);
                    photoRecycler.setAdapter(rightAdapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPreExecute() {

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {

        }
    });

}

private String encodeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    try{
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Statics.BITMAP_WIDTH, Statics.BITMAP_HEIGHT, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
        final byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imageInByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "";
    }

}



private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

}

This is my Fragment with conversations List:
    public class ConversationFragment extends Fragment {

```
private View v;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public ConversationFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @return A new instance of fragment ConversationFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ConversationFragment newInstance() {
    ConversationFragment fragment = new ConversationFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    //args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false);
    }

    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshconv);
    swipeRefresh.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    });
    swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mListener.syncDb();
        }
    });

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mListener.refreshConversations();
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

}

This is my Conversation Adapter:
    public class ConversationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private final File mStorageDir;
    private final RPCHelper mRPCHelper;
    private DataBaseReader.Conversation[] mDataset;

```
Context context;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public View mView;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mView = v;

    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public ConversationsAdapter(DataBaseReader.Conversation[] myDataset, File storageDir) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    mStorageDir = storageDir;
    mRPCHelper = new RPCHelper();
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public ConversationsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_conversations, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    context = parent.getContext();
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    Log.d("recy", "bind called");
    TextView username = (TextView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_username);
    final TextView message = (TextView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
    TextView date_and_time = (TextView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_date_and_time);
    ImageView status_pending = (ImageView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_status_conversation_pending);
    ImageView status_in = (ImageView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_status_conversation_in);
    TextView keyword0 = (TextView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.post_keywords0);
    TextView keyword1 = (TextView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.post_keywords1);
    TextView keyword2 = (TextView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.post_keywords2);
    ImageView userprofilpic = (ImageView)holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.img_userprofilpic);
    LinearLayout answer_info = (LinearLayout) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.answer_info);
    Button delete_coversation = (Button) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm_delete);



    userprofilpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("userId", mDataset[position].question.userId);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    username.setText(mDataset[position].question.userName);
    message.setText(mDataset[position].question.text);
    keyword0.setText(mDataset[position].question.keywords[0]);
    keyword1.setText(mDataset[position].question.keywords[1]);
    keyword2.setText(mDataset[position].question.keywords[2]);
    addImgToView(mDataset[position].question.photo, userprofilpic);

    if (Integer.parseInt(mDataset[position].confirmed) == 1) {
        status_pending.setEnabled(false);
        status_pending.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        status_in.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        answer_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                message.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                message.onSaveInstanceState();
                int convId = mDataset[position].id;
                Intent i = new Intent(context, ConversationActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("conversationId", "" + convId);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }


}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

private void addImgToView(final String uri, final ImageView v){
    mRPCHelper.getPhoto(mStorageDir + "/", uri, new AsyncResponseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap bm) {
            v.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
        }

    });
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

maintain a flag in data level to know is it read or unread,based on that you can apply the styles.

Comment: Thank you.Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: Maintain is read or unread in data , based on that you can apply different styles

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do this.
First you can ask to backend to write server side to query to handle last activity bases of timestamp .In this case you have to send your particular timestamp to server when you open particular conversation .
 Other you can make local database ex-(sql database) and handle it in your own code by updating query when you reading or undreading conversation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I'm a fresh newbie in Android and i supposed it could have been accessible for me..is it ? Could you be more descriptive?